# Como fazer o código gravar a informação de múltiplos arquivos?

Tags: php, fopen

Tenho um código de criar marca d'água em cada imagem que foi dado upload. No final deste código, gostaria que toda vez que uma pessoa fizesse upload da imagem, fosse criado um registro em um bloco de notas. Cheguei a este código mas estou com dificuldades para fazer com que ele guarde o registro dos múltiplos uploads.

```
$arquivo = "rastro.txt"; 
$data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");   
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$fp = fopen($arquivo, "w+");   
fwrite($fp,"Nome: $new_name | Data: $data | IP: $ip | Navegador: $browser");   
fclose($fp);
```

Como faço para gerar um loop no código ?

Comment: O loop seria depois de abrir o arquivo `fopen`, o `$new_name` você pega de onde?

Comment: Do código que cria as marcas d'água. É só essa parte aí que fiquei com dúvida mesmo, mas o $new_name está funcionando normal

Comment: Sim não tenho dúvidas disso, mais quando vc pega o `$new_name` é provável que você pegue de um array não?

Comment: Neste caso em especial, não :)

Comment: Bom, creio que para poder te ajudar preciso de mais informações, pq esse seu código está correto... mais preciso de mais informações do seu escopo, das variaveis que vc tem ai.

Comment: Bom, eu ainda estou aprendendo e por isso não repare no mangue kkk, mas segue aqui o código todo:
http://pastebin.com/5H6MTabs

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta, teste ai e veja se funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na forma como você abre o arquivo. Com o `w+` você abre o arquivo para leitura e gravação mais coloca o ponteiro de gravação sempre no começo do arquivo. Isso faz com que sempre sobreescreva os dados do arquivo, dando impressão que gravou apenas uma vez.

Considere utilizar `a` ou `a+` pois abre o arquivo e coloca o ponteiro de gravação no fim do arquivo.

```
$arquivo = "rastro.txt"; 
$data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");   
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");   
fwrite($fp,"Nome: $new_name | Data: $data | IP: $ip | Navegador: $browser \n\r");   
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado Jhonatan

Comment: Adicionei tambem no `fwrite` `\n\r` que serve para ir para a proxima linha, senão ia gravar tudo junto... kkkk